# Move yandex maps controllers in constructor

Tags: yandex, yandex-maps

can I change controls position with yandex map constructor?
My maps controls looks like that [image]
So i need to move all controlls to right a bit.
Using yandex API i can do it like that:

```
urMap.controls.add('zoomControl', {position: {left: '40px', top: '100px'}});
```

But can i reach it just using the [map-constructor](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change controls position only using [JavaScript API](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsapi/?from=SO) as described in your question.

[Map Constructor](https://yandex.com/map-constructor/?from=SO) is a simple service that allows to get a ready-to-use map code without programming but on the other hand it has [limited options](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/constructor/concepts/About-docpage/?from=SO) for map customization. Controls cannot be changed or moved.